# removeLast / addFirst methods in Deque JAVA

Tags: java, stack, queue, deque

I need help to solve my `removeLast` and `addFirst` methods.

I cannot think of a way to add an element to the head of my queue and to point the head to that element, since I only have access to `head.element` / `head.next`.

Likewise I cannot find a way to reference the tail of the queue after removing the last object, because I am restricted to `queue.element` and `queue.next`

Any help would be appreciated!

```
public class DequeImpl implements Deque{

    private Node head;
    private Node tail;
    private int size;

    public DequeImpl(){
        head=null;
        tail=null;
        size=0;
    }

    //This is a toString
    public String toString(){
        String toSend = "";
        Node baladeur = head;
        while(baladeur != null) {
            toSend += " " + baladeur.element;
            baladeur = baladeur.next;
        }
        return toSend;
    }

    // renvoie true if empty
    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return size==0;
    }


    public int size(){
        return this.size;
    }

   //To complete ///////
    public void addFirst(Object element){
        Node element2 = new Node(element, head);
        if(isEmpty()){
            head=tail=element2;
        }
        else{

        }
        size++;
    }

    public void addLast(Object element){
        Node element3 = new Node(element, null);
        if(isEmpty()){
            head=tail=element3;
        }
        else{
            tail.next=element3;
            tail = tail.suivant;
        }
        size++;
    }

    public Object removeFirst() throws QueueEmptyException{
        if(isEmpty())throw new QueueEmptyException("");
        Object element4 = head.element;
        if(size==1){
            head=tail=null;
        }
        else{
            head=head.next;
        }
            size--;
        return element4;
    }

   //To complete ///////

    public Object removeLast()throws QueueEmptyException{
        if(isEmpty())throw new QueueEmptyException("");
        Object element5 = tail.element;
        if(size==1){
            head=tail=null;
        }
        else{
            tail.next=null;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Object first()throws QueueEmptyException{
        if(isEmpty())throw new QueueEmptyException("");
        return head.element;

    }

    public Object last()throws QueueEmptyException{
        if(isEmpty())throw new QueueEmptyException("");
        return tail.element;
    }


    private class Node{
        private Object element;
        private Node next;

        private Node(Object element, Node next){
            this.element = element;
            this.next = next;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: In the line before the one you are missing, you assign a value to both `head` and `tail`. Why are you saying you have no access to them?

Comment: You can find the logic by simple Google searches, e.g. [Singly-linked list. Addition (insertion) operation](http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Singly-linked_list/Insertion).

Comment: @RealSkeptic I forgot to mention that there is a sub-class below, I have access to head and tail but I cannot think of a way to re-assign the head after adding an element. This is due to not having a head.previous function. This is a part of my academic work so i cannot make any changes to the class. Thanks for your time.

Comment: What does the subclass have to do with it? You keep a temporary reference to whatever `head` is pointing to. You then assign the new element to head, and fix the connections using the temporary reference you have kept.

Comment: @Andreas You're a top man, you hit the nail on the head. I believe this is what i was looking for, thanks for your help!

Comment: for the method addFirst, I entered: element2.next = head;  head = element2. Does this sound right?

Comment: If you go to the parent page of my previous link (http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Singly-linked_list), you'll also find a link for removal, including removeLast.

Answer (score 1):

Reassigning `head` is easy:

```
Node newHead = ... whatever you do here
newHead.next = head;
head = newHead;
```

I feel your pain with tail, though. If you don't have a back-pointer from `tail`, all you can do is iterate through the whole list, and:

```
if (tail.equals(thisNode.next)) {
  thisNode.next = null;
  tail = thisNode;
  break;
}
```

A little more context to show that you can iterate through the whole list:

```
Node thisNode = head;
while (thisNode != null) {
  if (tail.equals(thisNode.next)) {
    thisNode.next = null;
    tail = thisNode;
    break;
  }
  thisNode = thisNode.next;
}
```

Comment: Firstly, I'd like to thank you for answering. You are correct about the head part which seems correct. I am working with logic here which means that I cannot iterate through the list of elements, this is also where I struggle to find a solution to the problem.

Comment: Hmmm... You have `head`. `head` has a `.next`. You can iterate with that. (I used a lower case "i" because I'm not suggesting you use an `Iterator`. Do it the old-fashioned way and follow the next reference.) I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help. May I say your algorithm is very thoughtful and inspiring to me as a student. I guess I must practice a lot more :)